# Python 2.7 Match Exact String in the Row of a CSV File

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, match

I have a csv file containing strings in a specific column and other values in the others. I have also a list of strings.
Cycling over lines, I'd like to check if one of the strings in the list is exactly contained in the line of the csv file.
If yes, this line has to be written in a new csv file.

The csv file is a list of rows like:

```
22/06/2017 04:00:32 | string1 | value1   
22/06/2017 04:00:32 | string11 | value2    
22/06/2017 04:00:32 | string2 | value3   
22/06/2017 04:00:32 | string3 | value4
```

I wrote this code, it works fine but it doesn't consider the "exact" matching of strings.

```
import os, csv

def filter_csv(folderpath):

     list1 = [
     ('name1',1,'string1','value1'),
     ('name2',2,'string2','value2'),
     ('name3',3,'string3','value3'),
     ('name4',4,'string4','value4'),
     ...
     ]

     def column(matrix, i):
         return [row[i] for row in matrix]

     col = column(list1,2)

     for file in os.listdir("%s" % folderpath):
         if file.endswith(".csv"):
             new_file = 'new_'+file
             filepath = os.path.join("%s" % folderpath, file)
             new_filepath = os.path.join("%s" % folderpath, new_file)

             with open('%s' % filepath) as csvfile:
                 lines = csvfile.readlines()

             with open('%s' % new_filepath, 'wb') as csvfile2:
                 for line in lines:
                     for namevar in col:
                         if namevar in line:
                             csvfile2.write(line)

     return
```

How can I add the exact matching of strings for a column of the csv file?

Comment: "exact" matching I mean: if in the csv there is "string111" it writes in the new csv file because "string1" is contained in "string111", but I don't want so, I want to write in the new csv file only if there is "string1" in the first csv file.

Comment: The csv file is a list of rows likes:  22/06/2017  04:00:32 | string1 | value1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to present a slightly different solution using a different library, which now that I think about it might be overkill, but you might like it :) You should be able to modify the example to insert into into your code...

```
import pandas as pd

# Dummy col
col = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

# Read in CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter ="|")

# Strip all strings so that trailing whitespace is ignored. 
# csv library OP used would also be "fooled" by whitepace
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

# Select only rows with any column that has a value in col
df = df[df.isin(col).any(axis=1)]

# Write out CSV to new file
df.to_csv("test2.csv")
```

This will filter each row of the CSV by checking each column for one of the values in `col`. If any column has a value in `col` it appears in the output CSV file.

One thing I found was that if the text in the CSV had trailing whitespace the exact match wouldn't work. E.g, in the CSV line below `string1` would not be an exact match due to trailing whitespace.

```
 value1, value2, string1   , value3
```

Hence the extra code to trim all strings. Tested using the `csv` library and it would have the same problem. If you know that your CSV strings will never have trailing whitespace then you could even remove those two lines. Then the code to filter, in full form your example, would be (borrowing [Tomalak's use of `glob`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44703394/1517244)):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

def filter_csv(folderpath):

    list1 = [
        ('name1',1,'string1','value1'),
        ('name2',2,'string2','value2'),
        ('name3',3,'string3','value3'),
        ('name4',4,'string4','value4')
    ]

    def column(matrix, i):
        return [row[i] for row in matrix]

    col = column(list1,2)

    for filepath in glob.glob("%s/*.csv" % folderpath):
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(folderpath, 'new_' + filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter ="|")
        df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
        df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
        df[df.isin(col).any(axis=1)].to_csv(new_filepath, sep="|", header=False, index=False)
```

But if whitespace isn't an issue, you can trim the following lines out of the code:

```
 df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
 df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Comment: Great! This works! Just adding the argument  sep=';'  in the line:                 df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';' , header=None, skipinitialspace=True)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is write a filtered list to a file.

The filter condition is *"one of some predefined valid values must occur on the CSV line"* and we can use a set intersection for this. We need a set of valid values, and when you intersect those with the current input row and some remain then the current input row passes.

```
import os, csv
from glob import glob

def filter_csv(folderpath):

    list1 = [
        ('name1',1,'string1','value1'),
        ('name2',2,'string2','value2'),
        ('name3',3,'string3','value3'),
        ('name4',4,'string4','value4'),
        # ...
    ]

    # prepare a set of valid values
    valid_values = {row[2] for row in list1}

    for filepath in glob("%s/*.csv" % folderpath):
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        new_filepath = os.path.join(folderpath, 'new_' + filename)

        with open(filepath, newline='') as infile, \
            open(new_filepath, 'wb') as outfile:

            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            filtered_rows = (row for row in reader if valid_values.intersection(row))

            writer.writerows(filtered_rows)
```

Notes

- `glob()` is very useful for finding files by extension
- `with` can handle more than one resource
- you can use `\` to span multiple lines
- sets are optimized for looking up matching values
- `{ ... }` is a set comprehension - it turns a list into a set
- always parse CSV files using the CSV module - never use `.split()` or stuff like that

Comment: It doesn't work, I guess there is some mistake in the line with glob().

Comment: \*sigh\*, the `in` keyword was missing.

Comment: @bbastu In the code the OP shows all columns from the input file get compared to a certain list, not just a single one. At least that's how I interpreted it. Comparing only one column is simpler, no `.intersection()` call needed.

Comment: thnak you, but it doesn't match anything :-(

Comment: I showed you how to do it *in principle*. I meant you to understand the intention behind the code. Find the reason why it does not match anything and fix it. There are not too many moving parts in this code, so it should not take long.

Comment: @giube Hints: Does it read the input file properly, i.e. is it being split into columns properly? Does the `valid_values` set look correct? Can't be much more than one of those two things, really.